# Mapbox - How to check if linestring is in view

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

## Situation:

I use Mapbox to create a map with three markers + a linestring connecting them. Following [this exmaple](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/) I created a button that zooms the camera to the bounds of the linestring.

This works as intended.

Whenever the function is called (on click and on first map-load), the camera zooms to the linestring bounds correctly.

---

## Problem/Goal:

I would like to only display the button whenever:

- the user has changed position of the campera, after linestring was brought into view
- the user has changed the zoom, after linestring was brought into view

This can be simply done by adding / removing a `.is-visible` class.

However I somehow cant figure out how to listen to these two possible user interactions after linestring was brought into view.

I've tried some approaches that seemed overly complex and did not work. I have the feeling that the answer is quite simple, only I'm not seeing it.

Any help appreciated!

---

## Code:

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/mapbox@1.0.0-beta9/dist/mapbox-sdk.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.2.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.2.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map' class="traveljournal__map"></div>
<div class='traveljournal__map-actions'>
    <div id='zoomto' class="traveljournal__map-action traveljournal__map-action--zoomto"></div>
</div>

<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKENHERE';
    let client = new MapboxClient(mapboxgl.accessToken);


    // DEFINE MAP
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/nilsdannemann/cjz2kdev503jo1dnsr23qoca8',
        center: [174.724779, -41.288030], // Coordinates of newest Moment
        zoom: 9
    });


    // DEFINE MOMENTS
    var moments = [{
        id: "1",
        properties: {
            title: "moment title",
            content: "moment content",
            mood: "happy",
            date: "01. Aug 2019",
            weather: "sunny",
            iconSize: [60, 60],
            location: [174.800314, -41.317955],
        },
        camera: {
            center: [174.800314, -41.317955],
            zoom: 13,
            bearing: 20, // Add 20 for every location
            pitch: 40 
        }
    }, {
        id: "2",
        properties: {
            title: "moment title",
            content: "moment content",
            mood: "happy",
            date: "01. Aug 2019",
            weather: "sunny",
            iconSize: [60, 60],
            location: [174.773008, -41.282235],
        },
        camera: {
            center: [174.773008, -41.282235],
            zoom: 13,
            bearing: 40, // Add 20 for every location
            pitch: 40 
        }
    }, {
        id: "3",
        properties: {
            title: "moment title",
            content: "moment content",
            mood: "happy",
            date: "01. Aug 2019",
            weather: "sunny",
            iconSize: [60, 60],
            location: [174.724779, -41.288030],
        },
        camera: {
            center: [174.724779, -41.288030],
            zoom: 13,
            bearing: 60, // Add 20 for every location
            pitch: 40
        }
    }];


    // ADD MARKERS
    moments.forEach(function(marker, index) {
        // Create a DOM element for Marker
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'traveljournal__map-marker';
        el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
        el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            //Move Campera to Marker
            map.flyTo(moments[index].camera);
        });

        // Add Marker to Map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.properties.location)
            .addTo(map);
    }); 
    
    // ADD LINE BETWEEN MARKERS
    var linestring = [];
    moments.forEach(function(item) {
        linestring.push(item.properties.location);
    });

    // ADD ZOOM TO LINESTRING FUNCTION
    function zoomToLineString() {
        var bounds = linestring.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
            return bounds.extend(coord);
        }, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(linestring[0], linestring[0]));

        map.fitBounds(bounds, {
            padding: {top: 30, right: 0, bottom: 75, left: 0},
            bearing: 0,
            pitch: 0 
        });
    };

    // ADD ZOOM TO LINESTRING BUTTON EVENT
    document.getElementById('zoomto').addEventListener('click', function() {
        zoomToLineString();
    });
    
    // LOAD MAP
    map.on('load', function() {

        // ADD LINE TO MAP
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "route",
            "type": "line",
            "source": {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {},
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": linestring
                    }
                }
            },
            "layout": {
                "line-join": "round",
                "line-cap": "round"
            },
            "paint": {
                "line-color": "#2BABEE",
                "line-width": 2
            }
        });

        // ZOOM TO LINESTRING ON MAP LOAD
        zoomToLineString();

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `zoomend` and `moveend` events to perform your bounds check, and update classes as required. You can use `queryRenderedFeatures` to see if the line is (partially) somewhere in the viewport.

```
function checkLine() {
   if (map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers: 'route'}).length) {
      // route is within view, do what you want
   }
}

map.on('zoomend', checkLine);
map.on('moveend', checkLine);
```

Comment: Thanks. Only issue: this wont show the zoom button when the user has zoomed OUT, right? I am trying to have the button apper whenever the camera after the zoomToLineString has happened.

Comment: Probably the `moveend` event by itself is enough to trigger on any kind of zoom or pan.